# Could not find androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I copied the dependencies mentioned in the website here: https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started#kts to use Navigation Component. However, when i run the project, it says it **could not find androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:**. I've tried included **$nav_version** which is = **2.3.5**, but the problem remains. Is there anything I missed out?

**Screenshot without $nav_version:**
[image]

**Screenshot with $nav_version:**
[image]

Comment: You did not pass the version of dependency  ->  

implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:$nav_version"

Comment: @Rajasekhar it shows the same problem. I've added a screenshot to show the error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Navigation Compose was introduced after Navigation 2.3 - you need to use Navigation 2.4 (latest at this time is 2.4.0-rc01):

```
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.4.0-rc01"
```